# Working with the same variable across the jQuery .ready() defined in multiple scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say that I have a HTML that links to two scripts:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="general.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="specific.js"></script>
...
```

Each of the two scripts has it's own jQuery's `.ready()` defined.

**general.js:**

```
jQuery(function() {
  var foo;
  $('#btn').click(function() {alert(foo())});
}
```

**specific.js:**

```
jQuery(function() {
  foo = function() {alert("hello")};
  $('#btn').click(function() {foo()});
}
```

where `#btn` is a button element.

When I clicked on `#btn` I was expecting to see "hello" dialog, but instead, I got `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in chrome developer tools.

My own understanding is that `foo` should have been assigned the function already, instead of being undefined, before it's accessed by the `click` event. Obviously, my understanding is incorrect. Can someone please explain to me why it's behaving the way it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring "foo" with `var` **inside** the first function. It's therefore local to that function and not visible external to it.

You could make "foo" global by declaring it *outside* the first "ready" handler.

Global variables are kind-of undesirable; it might be nicer to keep the value as a "data" value on the element itself.

```
$(function() {
   $('#btn').data('foo', 'some value');
   $('#btn').click(function() {alert($(this).data('foo'))});
}
```

That way the data is associated with the elements (though not directly on the DOM objects; jQuery keeps track of the values in an internal map to avoid DOM-related memory leaks) and you don't pollute the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Yes, I want to avoid making `foo` global. Unfortunately, your other solution does not really help with my actual problem, in which the function assigned to `foo` is much more complex than `alert(...)`.

Is there any way that I can combine the two anonymous functions in the `.ready()` while maintaining multiple `.ready()`?

Comment: Well there's no way to *mechanically* combine separate functions after the fact, other than to make them somehow non-anonymous and call them in series from a single function.  It's not really clear to me what your larger issue is; perhaps that would be a good topic for a separate question.

Comment: Maybe what you could do is extend the jQuery object, similar to the way jQuery plugins do, so you could call it as `$.foo()`. This only pollutes the jQuery namespace, not the global namespace.

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks. I started another SO question. Feel free to add your answer to it if you want. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632068/multiple-jquery-ready-appending-to-existing-event-handler-instead-of-creati#comment17034220_12632068)